# The requested Payment Method is not available

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I'm trying to create order programmatically by following code but getting payment not available.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($data->user);
$quote =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); 
// Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);          
$quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote->getShippingAddress();

// Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
          ->collectShippingRates()
          ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
          ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));
try {
    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    // Create Order From Quote
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$quote = $customer = $service = null;
// Finished
echo  $increment_id;
```

Comment: Did you enable cheque or money order payment method in admin panel ?

Comment: yes it is enabled , i'm creating these orders by custom extension ,normal order works fine

Comment: check all condition is satisfied or not ( Payment from Specific Countries , Minimum Order Total ) for Check / Money order

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to track without the full quote information & your store configuration, but have a look at the source of the error, from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php`'s `importData` function:

```
...
$this->getQuote()->collectTotals();

if (!$method->isAvailable($this->getQuote())
    || !$method->isApplicableToQuote($this->getQuote(), $data->getChecks())
) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('The requested Payment Method is not available.'));
}
```

There are two reasons you may be getting this error, either:

1. The method is not available, or,
2. The method is not applicable to the quote

Firstly, check that the method for Cheque / Money Order is enabled in `System` → `Configuration` → `Sales` → `Payment Methods`

Secondly, check that your quotation is satisfying the requirements of the payment method (minimum order total, maximum order total, allowed countries etc.)